# How to use twitter bootstrap as a third party component in Joomla 2.5?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, joomla, responsive-design, components, joomla2.5

I'm using **Joomla 2.5** with **RESPONSIVE TEMPLATE**. But my component is not responsive.
how can i change my component responsive using **TWITTER BOOTSTRAP** ?

Any one knows Pls give me suggestion

Thanks

Prasanna

Comment: Without code it's very difficult to help you. Did you add `bootstrap-responsive.css`?

Comment: have a look at the Bootstrap docs and how it works. As Pigueiras said, it's difficult to even you in the slightest way as no code or specific issues have been mentioned or provided. So please do so and you will get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

An interesting challenge. As others have pointed out, without seeing an example URL there's no way to give you specific suggestions, but this would get you started.

- Include the bootstrap css and optionally bootstrap.js, either site wide by adding them to the template, or use an extension like [JS CSS Control](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/site-performance/20075) and load them only on specific pages
- The custom CSS will need will probably need to target elements just on pages which use the extension. If it's module add a module class suffix (under the module manager > advanced settings), or if it's a menu item, a link CSS style (under menu manager > link > link type options)
- Bootstrap js will be needed for some plugins and components, so you may or may not need this. If you do you'll also have to add jQuery before you call the bootstrap.js. Since you are using Joomla 2.5, MooTools will be loaded by default. This may clash with jQuery so either [use an extension to load jQuery](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/jquery-scripts/10236?qh=YTo2OntpOjA7czo2OiJqcXVlcnkiO2k6MTtzOjk6IidqcXVlcnknLCI7aToyO3M6ODoiJ2pxdWVyeSciO2k6MztzOjc6ImpxdWVyeSciO2k6NDtzOjMyOiInanF1ZXJ5JywnanF1ZXJ5dWknLCdqcXVlcnlmb3JtJyI7aTo1O3M6ODoianF1ZXJ5J3MiO30=) or you may be able to [disable mootools](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/mootools/22236)

Then the fun part begins.

- With a browser go to a page which is using the extension, inspect elements inserted by the extension, and look for elements which have hard coded dimensions and use a custom CSS stylesheet to override these with percentage values.

  So for example if there's an image with hardcoded dimensions, and you use **make-responsive** for your module class suffix above, the custom css would be something like

  .make-responsive img {
  width: 30%;
  height: auto; 
  }

  In practice there may well be multiple images inserted by the extension and you need to style them differently, so look for other properties or classes than you can hook into to target just the image in question (eg `.make-responsive table img {..}` )
- To further refine the process, you may need to use [media queries](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/) to target different device widths
- Inspect what happens when you play with the browser width. Maybe you'll need to add floats and clears to some selectors at certain viewports to get the arrangement you want, or maybe you'll even need to hide some elements.

If you are lucky this will be all you need to do. If the extension relies heavily on table layouts, then that might be difficult to work with.

Good luck!